# Get current subscription id in parameter file

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have such a **azuredeploy.parameters.json** file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "adminLogin": {
      "value": "exampleadmin"
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/[subscription().subscriptionId]/resourceGroups/ARMTemplate/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/dev-kv"

        },
        "secretName": "ExamplePassword"
      }
    },
    "sqlServerName": {
      "value": "TestServer"
    }

  }
}
```

My aim is to extract the current subscriptionId and integrate it into the `id`.
Is it possible in parameter file to do this job?

Answer (score 0):

if it works, the correct syntax would be:

```
"id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/ARMTemplate/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/dev-kv')]"
```

if it doesnt work you can use a nested deployment to pass it as an argument to a nested deployment and return the value from it or just execute your stuff in a nested deployment