# JSON Parameter file string concatination

Tags: json, arm

This is one of the entry from my JSON parameter file

```
 "id": "/subscriptions/074ed3db-3d7f-4462-8432-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/network-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/hub-vnet/subnets/sub1"
```

Instead of hardcode the subscription name/id with in the line, is there any way to use subscription().id function in the parameter file itself and continate with in the same line,

```
 "id": "/subscriptions/"+'subscription().id'+"/resourceGroups/network-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/hub-vnet/subnets/sub1"
```

the above line is not working. Any help would be appraciated.

Edited

Sorry for lack of information in the initial post. This parameter file will we read by a PowerShell script, which do the deployment.

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment   `
                            -Name $DeploymentName `
                            -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                            -TemplateFile $templateFile `
                            -TemplateParameterFile $parameterFile `
                            -Verbose `
                            -AsJob
```

I am looking for the correct syntax to get this done, how can I use the string concat or similar function and input subscription ID in between the string value.

Thanks

Comment: Context to all this? Who is using the JSON file, and in what way is it not working? Does `subscription().id` need to be quoted, I'd expect it shouldn't be. It might also be `subscription.id()`. But really ... who is reading and interpreting this JSON, and what does it say about calling functions?

Comment: More information added to to the post. Its mainly syntax error. How can add the subscription ID in between the string value dynamically.?

Comment: I have tried this one, but no luck, 
"id": "'/subscriptions/',[concat(subscription().id,'/resourceGroups/network-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/hub-vnet/subnets/sub1')]"

Comment: Is this Azure related? Is there a manual for TemplateParameterFile? Are there any error messages (or, how do you know it's "not working")?

Comment: I have the same issue as in this post, the solution given there is not working for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060384/get-current-subscription-id-in-parameter-file/64318952#64318952